# Cannot install libpulse-dev in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-20.04, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I like to use PocketSphinx speech recognition engine. For that, libpulse-dev is one of the dependencies. However, I cannot install libpulse-dev in my system.

I used the following command to install the package:

`sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev`

And I get the following output:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libpulse-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpulse-dev' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is misconfigured, edit it as follows:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpulse-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone are using CentOS 7 try do this:

sudo yum install pulseaudio-libs-devel
sudo yum install alsa-lib-devel -y

sudo yum install portaudio
pip3 install --upgrade pocketsphinx

...or try it:

pip3 install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio